# Formatting numbers in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How i can format values in SSRS in this format

```
"_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* -?_);_(@_)"
```

This is Excel formatting style, but how to make the same in SSRS

Comment: Can you give an example with a real value?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to properties for the textbox, copy and paste the string into the Format field.

If this does not give the desired results, please describe the difference in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom format in SSRS by navigating to place holder properties of particular field, and then navigating to 'number' tab. In category section we have option to defined our custom number format. so you can define your custom format there.